# Can this be used instead of "and so on"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Can "etc", "so on" also be used as "and things of that nature".

Example:
In school you need to have, pen, pencil, pencil case and things of that nature.

English is not my first language, I hope you understand my question.
Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98672/discussion-on-question-by-meli-can-this-be-used-instead-of-and-so-on).

Answer (score 1):

*Etc.* is short for *et cetera*, which is Latin for *and others*. It is used in exactly the sense you describe, at the end of a short list to mean 'and other things of the same kind'.

Comment: your 'and others' appears to refer to persons, which is not true of the
neutral 'et cetera'

Comment: @Toothrot I certainly did not mean to imply a reference to 'other people'; I meant  'and others like them'.